# Rick and morty API returning all results with an ID of 0

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I'm pretty stuck on this and I'm not sure why it's happening.

(Using Vue 3 and axios)
I have a method that I call in the mounted lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
this.getList();
}
```

and my get list request:

```
async getList() {
this.axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character').then((response) => {
     console.log(response.data);
     this.apiReturn = response.data;
     });
}
```

Now up until this morning, this was all good. But now when I look at my console log all of the id's are set to 0:

[image]

But if you go to the request URL in the browser it has all the id's listed correctly:
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

I feel like I'm losing my mind. The only thing I can see is if I've made too many requests while building this and instead of returning an error, it's just returning data without id's.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, i'm an idiot. Had a button deeply nested down mutating the props because I wrote a :disabled="" check wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).